# returning date with traffic intensity from tuples in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I'm trying to return all the dates that match with the traffic intensity in the function below but am getting all the elements of only the first tuple as a list instead of all tuples that match.

```
def traffic_intensity(count):
   """Returns string indicating intensity level given by number of 
    vehicles"""
    level_name = ""
    if(count < 5000):
        level_name = "Very Low"
    elif(count >= 5000 and count < 10000):
        level_name = "Low"
    elif(count >= 10000 and count < 18000):
       level_name = "Moderate"
    elif(count >= 18000):
        level_name = "High"
    return(level_name)


def dates_with_intensity(vehicle_records, intensity):
    """Returns number of days with the given traffic intensity level"""
    new_list = []
    for number in vehicle_records:
        date_count = number[0]
        number_count = number[1]
        traffic = traffic_intensity(number_count)
        if traffic == intensity:
            new_list += date_count
        return new_list
```

For the test data

```
vehicle_records = [('2010-01-01',1),
                ('2010-01-02',2),
                ('2010-01-03',3)]
days = dates_with_intensity(vehicle_records, 'Very Low')
print(days)
```

I am supposed to be getting

```
['2010-01-01', '2010-01-02', '2010-01-03']
```

but instead am getting

```
['2', '0', '1', '0', '-', '0', '1', '-', '0', '1']
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Can you post some sample data that you expect this to work with (i.e `vehicle_records`)?

Comment: @JosephM just did :)

Comment: Just as an FYI, `count >= 5000 and count < 10000` can  very neatly be replaced by `5000 <= count < 10000` in Python. Any sequence of rich comparison operators `a op1 b op2 c ...` gets effectively computed as `a op1 b and b op2 c ...`. The only difference is that if `a`, `b` or `c` are complex expressions, they only get evaluated once.

Comment: Also, you don't need to parenthesize the `if` and `elif` expressions.

Comment: Well posed question though.+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the return out of the for loop. Also date_count isn't an array so you should be using `.append()` not addition:

```
def dates_with_intensity(vehicle_records, intensity):
"""Returns number of days with the given traffic intensity level"""
    new_list = []
    for number in vehicle_records:
        date_count = number[0]
        number_count = number[1]
        traffic = traffic_intensity(number_count)
        if traffic == intensity:
            new_list.append(date_count)
    return new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues, one is `return` is inside `for` loop which causes to look into only one item. And other is you may need to extend array `new_list` with `date_count`. You can try as following:

```
def dates_with_intensity(vehicle_records, intensity):
    """Returns number of days with the given traffic intensity level"""
    new_list = []
    for number in vehicle_records:
        date_count = number[0]
        number_count = number[1]

        traffic = traffic_intensity(number_count)
        if traffic == intensity:
            new_list += [date_count] # extend as array
    return new_list # move return
```

For testing similar scenario, you can consider following example:

```
l = []
l += "string"
print(l)
```

Result:

```
['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

Instead:

```
l = []
l += ["string"]
print(l)
```

Result:

```
['string']
```

For more, I would suggest looking into [relevant discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/difference-between-append-vs-extend-list-methods-in-python).

## Update:

I think the code can be little shorter with `list comprehension` and removing condition in `elif` with following:

```
def traffic_intensity(count):
    """Returns string indicating intensity level given by number of vehicles"""
    if (count < 5000): return "Very Low"
    elif(count < 10000): return "Low"
    elif(count < 18000): return "Moderate"
    else: return "High"
    

def dates_with_intensity(vehicle_records, intensity):
    """Returns number of days with the given traffic intensity level"""
    return [date for date, num in vehicle_records if intensity == traffic_intensity(num)]
```

Comment: You can also unpack in a `for`, for more descriptive variable names e.g. `[date for date, num in ... traffic_intensity(num)]`

Comment: @AChampion (*edited*) thanks! I think it makes more easier to understand.